# Is Apple signaling the intention to phase out MacOS?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ios, ipad

In the recent Apple [what's a computer ad](https://youtu.be/sQB2NjhJHvY) for iPad there is a clear hint that a *computer* is no longer something that 'young cool kids' care about.

Are there any known unambiguous indicators that a convergence of MacOS and iOS is planned?

My understanding is that currently Apple has no dedicated MacOS dev team, only an iOS team which backports iOS features to MacOS. MacOS seems to be dragging behind iOS as a lower priority, less profitable 'image' project.

I understand it is currently a speculative topic, but are there any publicly available statements or recorded evidence about what's on the books? Are we going to see a sexed up iPad that will eventually replace the MacBooks (including Pro) or a unified cross-platform AppleOS that will run on Macs, iPhones, and iPads?

Comment: Your understanding is clearly wrong. Sierra introduced many new MacOS features that aren’t in iOS and so can’t have been backported. High Sierra didn’t, but that kind of tick-tock cycle is normal for MacOS releases.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is speculating about Apple‘s strategy

Comment: @patrix: the question states clearly that it is about recorded facts and collected indicators; not about opinions and predictions. It is a yes/no question.

Comment: From [the FAQ](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): „... specific questions about what Apple [did|does|thinks|might do] are not helpful in a Q&A setting since they lack a practical problem to be solved.“. The only facts on this topic can come from Apple, everything else is speculation, especially things analysts write (to compare: 18 months ago analysts predicted the end of professional Mac models, today we have the iMac Pro and the upcoming Mac Pro)

Comment: Thanks for the FAQ quote. I agree the question might not fit into the SO concept; just couldn't think of other places to ask.

Comment: The question *is* interesting, we are just the wrong site for that. You could try to engage in a discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat) but it's probably too low in participation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mark Gurman (Bloomberg)](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2017-12-20/apple-is-said-to-have-plan-to-combine-iphone-ipad-and-mac-apps) says that iOS and macOS apps will merge soon but previously **Apple has been against merging the actual operating systems**.

> Starting as early as next year, software developers will be able to design a single application that works with a touchscreen or mouse and trackpad depending on whether it’s running on the iPhone and iPad operating system or on Mac hardware, according to people familiar with the matter.

The iPad Pro has been recommended by Apple for casual users (web browsing etc), saying that a Mac is overkill for them. Obviously professionals will still need full blown Macs for complex software applications but likely we’ll start seeing decent Text Editors etc. arrive on the iPad.

—

UPDATE: relevant [blog post (Daring Fireball)](https://daringfireball.net/2017/12/marzipan) criticizing the Bloomberg article’s focus:

> Mark Gurman had an intriguing story at Bloomberg this week, but the problems start with the headline itself: “Apple Plans Combined iPhone, iPad and Mac Apps to Create One User Experience”.
>
> Gurman probably didn’t write the headline, but it doesn’t even make sense. iOS has no concept of a mouse cursor and runs only on touchscreen devices. MacOS has no support for touchscreen devices and requires a mouse pointer. “One user experience” is neither possible nor desirable. The truth is that this effort by Apple is almost certainly not about cross-platform applications but instead cross-platform frameworks for developers. It’s developer news, not user news.